# Loading unsafe scripts

Tags: php, vbulletin

I am operating a vBulletin 4.2.2 forum(vbulletin.com). The issue is that whenever I save something(e.g: saving changes to edits on a user's profile / usergroup edit), the screen is blank. WHY? Because I am using HTTPS and I guess chrome detects the content as an "unsafe script". Are there any possible workarounds I can use without having to turn off HTTPS throughout the admin panel?

Comment: why would chrome think it is an "unsafe script"? Chrome would only be able to see client side stuff like html and javascript. PHP is server side and the chrome doesn't even see that stuff. Check your error logs (linux/apache defaults to `/var/logs/apache2/error.log`) and see what is happening.

Comment: Well I don't know, as the back-end part does get executed, this works fine without using HTTPS and also it says in the corner with that little shield icon "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources". How am I able to authenticate the source?

Comment: "unauthenticated sources" means that it is trying to load a script from another site that isn't using https while your site is on https. Usually combining https with external stuff from http is bad practice, but nothing that would stop the page from load. In some browsers/cases it might even ask you if you want to load the page. The blank screen is likely a php error and you have display_errors set to off. Check your php error log to see what the real issue is.

Comment: That isn't the issue, as I said - everything works perfect when HTTPS is off. I believe it may be because I am using a subdomain? All subdomains, etc everything is https enabled through cloudflare so I have no idea why that should be an issue.

Comment: Well, apparently there is some script/resource that isn't being routed through cloudflare. That is why you would get the "unauthenticated sources" message. It is possible it loads a script from another site such as google's cdn or elsewhere. If you look at the source, you will find something in there saying http instead of https.

Comment: But how can I fix the issue?

Comment: You could try to fix where that script is pointing to (if a https version exists). That would fix that message. Other than that, for the blank screen it is either an issue with cloudflare not loading the page or you are having a php error that would show up in the php logs.